# fs.statSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, fs

Node version: `10.16.3`

I'm so confused. Apparently `fs.statSync` in the following code is not a function... Can somebody please explain to me why the following code is throwing this error?

```
fs.readFile('./config.json', 'utf8',
  (error, config) => {
    console.log(`1. ${config}`)
    if (error) console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
    else {
      for (const archive of JSON.parse(config).archives){
        console.log(`2. ${archive}`)
        console.log(`3. ${fs.statSync(archive).isDirectory()}`)
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Console

```
1. {
  "archives": [
    "C:\\Windows",
    "C:\\AMD",
    "C:\\MSOCache",
    "C:\\PerfLogs",
    "C:\\Program Files",
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)",
    "C:\\ProgramData",
    "C:\\Users",
    "C:\\WebDrivers"
  ]
}

2. C:\Windows

3. Uncaught TypeError: fs.statSync is not a function
    at file-system.js:128
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:61)
```

Comment: what nodejs version? and are you doing a simple `const fs = require('fs')` at the top?

Comment: @TravisWebb node v 10.16.3 -- and yes im requiring `fs` which is why `readFile` itself isnt throwing errors

Comment: So, I'd highly recommend that you NOT do `const fs = require('fs').promises`.  Use some different symbol than `fs` so this won't confuse you or others looking at your code.  Reserve `fs` for the regular fs module functions (the non-promise versions).  Personally, I do `const fsp = require('fs').promises;` myself and use `fsp` as the promise version.  Then, I can even have both `fs` and `fsp` available if needed.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah i was doing that, but sometimes if i just wanna code something quickly ill forego it. but prolly best to stick to that either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your promisifying `fs`. It won't promisify the synchronous methods.

You rarely want to use the `Sync` methods anyhow, they'll clog up your event loop.

Comment: same issue with using a variable. in fact, thats what i was trying to do initially and then removed setting it as a variable to create the MVP

Comment: omg u know what i think it is. im using `fs.promises` as `fs` instead of vanilla `fs`

Comment: yep that might be it.