# ERROR TypeError: fs_1.statSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I know that the error is discussed on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584103/fs-statsync-is-not-a-function), but I don't think it's quite the same.

Based on [this example](http://I%20have%20an%20Angular), I want to open a report based on a dropdown report name selection. But first I have to get in a dropdown the existing files from a folder. I don't know if this how it should be done, but I found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readdir) that `readdir` could do what I want. I have installed it using `npm i readdir`. After running ng serve command, I get the following errors:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/dist/src/index.js Module
> not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\ProiectVisualStudio\Reporting_how-to-use-the-web-report-designer-in-javascript-with-angular-t566422-19.2.3-\JS\angular-report-designer\node_modules@kwsites\file-exists\dist\src'

> ERROR in ./node_modules/readdir/dist/util/directory.js Module not
> found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\ProiectVisualStudio\Reporting_how-to-use-the-web-report-designer-in-javascript-with-angular-t566422-19.2.3-\JS\angular-report-designer\node_modules\readdir\dist\util'

> ERROR in ./node_modules/readdir/dist/util/file-stat.js Module not
> found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\ProiectVisualStudio\Reporting_how-to-use-the-web-report-designer-in-javascript-with-angular-t566422-19.2.3-\JS\angular-report-designer\node_modules\readdir\dist\util'

> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ ** i ｢wdm｣: Failed to
> compile.

These were resolved by adding in `package.json` file this section of code:

```
"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
```

The problem I have now is that I get in browser'console this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: fs_1.statSync is not a function
    at check (index.js:12)
    at Object.exists (index.js:40)
    at readSync (read-dir.js:47)
    at ReportViewerComponent.ngOnInit (report-viewer.component.ts:52)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31910)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:12)
```

My report-viewer-component.html:

```
<div>
  <form #filter="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="filterta(filter)" style="display: flex;">
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedReport" name="something" (ngModelChange)="onReportChange()">
      <option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
      <!-- <option value="1">January</option> -->
    </select>
  </form>

  <dx-report-viewer [reportUrl]="reportUrl" height="800px">
    <dxrv-request-options [invokeAction]="invokeAction" [host]="hostUrl"></dxrv-request-options>
  </dx-report-viewer>
</div>
```

My report-viewer-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import 'devexpress-reporting/dx-richedit';
import { DxReportViewerComponent } from 'devexpress-reporting-angular';
import { readSync, ABSOLUTE_PATHS, CASELESS_SORT } from 'readdir';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-viewer',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './report-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    "../../../node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css",
    "../../../node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css",
    "../../../node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css",
    "../../../node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-analytics.common.css",
    "../../../node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-analytics.light.css",
    "../../../node_modules/devexpress-reporting/dist/css/dx-webdocumentviewer.css"
  ]

})
export class ReportViewerComponent implements OnInit {


  @ViewChild(DxReportViewerComponent, { static: true }) viewer: DxReportViewerComponent;
  @ViewChild('selectedReport', { static: false }) public selectedReport: "C:\\ProiectVisualStudio\\Reporting_how-to-use-the-web-report-designer-in-javascript-with-angular-t566422-19.2.3-\\CS\\ServerSide\\Reports";
  title = 'DXReportViewerSample';
  hostUrl = 'http://localhost:54111/';
  invokeAction: string = "/WebDocumentViewer/Invoke";
  
  reportUrl: string = 'TestDB';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const allTextFilesFilter = ['*.repx'];//my report extension
    const options = ABSOLUTE_PATHS + CASELESS_SORT;
    const contents = readSync('C:\\ProiectVisualStudio\\Reporting_how-to-use-the-web-report-designer-in-javascript-with-angular-t566422-19.2.3-\\CS\\ServerSide\\Reports', allTextFilesFilter, options);    
    contents.forEach(path => console.log(`Matched path: "${path}"`));
  }
}
```

My npm version: 6.14.15

My node version: v14.17.6

Angular CLI: 8.3.29

rxjs: 6.4.0

typescript: 3.5.3

webpack: 4.39.2

How could I get rid of `ERROR TypeError: fs_1.statSync is not a function`, or my method of getting in a dropdown the existing files from a folder is wrong?

Comment: You cannot use NodeJS modules in a web application. NodeJS is server-side, web applications run in the browser.

Comment: @rveerd thanks for reply! Do you know any method how could I do what I want?

Comment: What do you want to do? You cannot access the local file system from the browser. If you want the user to upload a file, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-file-upload) will help.

Comment: @rveerd I want to open a report based on a dropdown report name selection. File upload I don't think would help me. 
For example, on a folder I have saved 3 reports (.repx). These 3 reports I want to be in dropdown list and if someone chooses from it report 2, this should be opened in report viewer. But I don't know hot to get those 3 reports in my dropdown list.